# Intento hacer un Insert desde una tabla a otra en SQL SERVER desde PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

```
Me aparece el siguiente mensaje cuando lo ejecuto e intento hacer el insert en mi tabla`enter code here`: [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '�'. ) )
```

Utilizo SQL SERVER, PHP 7.2 y XAMPP para la conexión.
Desde el Management Studio puedo realizar las inserciones sin inconvenientes, pero al momento de hacerlo desde PHP, me lanza este error de SQL.

```
Este es mi código:
<?php

include "conexión_básica.php";

$json = file_get_contents('data_matriculaciones.json');
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($data as $row) {
                                $anio = $row['anio'];
                                $codigo_departamento = $row['codigo_departamento'];
                                $nombre_departamento = $row['nombre_departamento'];
                                $codigo_distrito = $row['codigo_distrito'];
                                $nombre_distrito = $row['nombre_distrito'];
                                $codigo_barrio_localidad = $row['codigo_barrio_localidad'];
                                $nombre_barrio_localidad = $row['nombre_barrio_localidad'];
                                $codigo_zona = $row['codigo_zona'];
                                $nombre_zona = $row['nombre_zona'];
                                $codigo_establecimiento = $row['codigo_establecimiento'];
                                $codigo_institucion = $row['codigo_institucion'];
                                $sector_o_tipo_gestion = $row['sector_o_tipo_gestion'];
                                $nombre_institucion = $row['nombre_institucion'];
                                $matricula_cientifico = $row['matricula_cientifico'];
                                $matricula_tecnico = $row['matricula_tecnico'];
                                $matricula_media_abierta = $row['matricula_media_abierta'];
                                $matricula_formacion_profesional_media = 
                                $row['matricula_formacion_profesional_media'];
                                $id = $row['id'];
                                $anho_cod_geo = $row['anho_cod_geo'];
                                $matricula_cientifico_hombre = $row['matricula_cientifico_hombre'];
                                $matricula_cientifico_mujer = $row['matricula_cientifico_mujer'];
                                $matricula_tecnico_hombre = $row['matricula_tecnico_hombre'];
                                $matricula_tecnico_mujer = $row['matricula_tecnico_mujer'];
                                $matricula_media_abierta_hombre = 
                                $row['matricula_media_abierta_hombre'];
                                $matricula_media_abierta_mujer = $row['matricula_media_abierta_mujer'];
                                $matricula_formacion_profesional_media_hombre = 
                                $row['matricula_formacion_profesional_media_hombre'];

$consultasql="INSERT INTO tabla_Privado_Subvencionado (anio, codigo_departamento ,nombre_departamento, codigo_distrito, nombre_distrito, 
codigo_barrio_localidad, nombre_barrio_localidad, codigo_zona, nombre_zona, codigo_establecimiento, codigo_institucion, 
sector_o_tipo_gestion, nombre_institucion, matricula_cientifico, matricula_tecnico, matricula_media_abierta, 
matricula_formacion_profesional_media, id, anho_cod_geo, matricula_cientifico_hombre, matricula_cientifico_mujer, 
matricula_tecnico_hombre, matricula_tecnico_mujer, matricula_media_abierta_hombre, matricula_media_abierta_mujer, matricula_formacion_profesional_media_hombre)

SELECT $anio, $codigo_departamento, $nombre_departamento, $codigo_distrito, $nombre_distrito, $codigo_barrio_localidad, $nombre_barrio_localidad, $codigo_zona, $nombre_zona, $codigo_establecimiento, $codigo_institucion, $sector_o_tipo_gestion, $nombre_institucion,
```

$matricula_cientifico, $matricula_tecnico, $matricula_media_abierta, $matricula_formacion_profesional_media, $id, $anho_cod_geo, $matricula_cientifico_hombre, $matricula_cientifico_mujer, $matricula_tecnico_hombre, $matricula_tecnico_mujer, $matricula_media_abierta_hombre, $matricula_media_abierta_mujer, $matricula_formacion_profesional_media_hombre

```
FROM tabla_matriculas WHERE sector_o_tipo_gestion = 'Privado Subvencionado'";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $consultasql);
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo $row['anio'].", ".$row['id']."<br />";

}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

}

?>
```

Comment: El símbolo del error no aparece correctamente, mira a ver si puedes corregirlo. De todos modos si en el Management Studio te funciona y por código no, es posible que sea porque alguno de los parámetros sea nulo o contenga algún caracter extraño.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo no tienes ningún carácter extraño en el código, lo mas seguro es que los datos que ingresas tenga alguna 'ñ' y por eso te marque el error.

Igual en el insert into no veo el values... no conosco php pero en sql server si quieres insertar un valor a una tabla seria tipo..

```
INSERT INTO tb1 ("V1","V2","V3") VALUES ("01","02","03")
```